# extracting list of variables in the final model when using stepAIC() function

Tags: r

I'm wanting to extract a list of the variable names in the final model when using the
`stepAIC()` function.

I've tried:

```
attr(terms(backward.aic), "predvars")
```

but this is not giving me a list.

Answer (score 0):

What about listing the `term.labels`?

```
list(attr(terms(quine.stp), "term.labels"))
# [[1]]
#  [1] "Eth"         "Sex"         "Age"         "Lrn"         "Eth:Sex"    
#  [6] "Eth:Age"     "Eth:Lrn"     "Sex:Age"     "Sex:Lrn"     "Age:Lrn"    
# [11] "Eth:Sex:Lrn" "Eth:Age:Lrn"
```

---

*Data*

```
library(MASS)
quine.hi <- aov(log(Days + 2.5) ~ .^4, quine)
quine.nxt <- update(quine.hi, . ~ . - Eth:Sex:Age:Lrn)
quine.stp <- stepAIC(quine.nxt,
                     scope = list(upper = ~Eth*Sex*Age*Lrn, lower = ~1),
                     trace = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe names(backward.aic$model) ? found it through its str()